# Printing decryption results on a different line

Tags: python, loops, encryption

I am in the process of writing a python script that using the caesar cipher technique will decrypt text which it does not know the key. I was wondering if there was a way, or rather what is the way, to print each decryption attempt to a new line and what key that line used. I.E. 5 line would say something like "Key = 5, decryption = HELLO" I have tried counting the length of the string to be decrypted and using that to loop the script but to no avail. I am new to python so I do apologise if this a a rather basic piece of code.

```
message = raw_input('Enter encrypted text: ')
decryption_message = ""
l = message.__len__()
print l
for x in range(0, 26):
    for c in message:
        for d in range (l):
            m = ord(c) - 65
            e = (int(m) - int(x)) %26
            ea = e + 65
            decryption_message = decryption_message + chr(ea)
print decryption_message
```

Comment: Just indent the last line and add x: `print x, decrypt_message`.

Comment: Just tips: Using `zip()` can make this code much shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this now lets you input your own alphabet, such as

```
 string.ascii_lowercase 

 string.ascii_uppercase

 string.ascii_letters


import string  #you need to import string 
# you enter your choice of ascii char sets(above) for the arg 'alpha', by default though it's ascii_letters
def decrypt_print(alpha=string.ascii_letters):
    message = raw_input('Enter encrypted text: ')
    de = ""
    l = len(message) # the proper way to call len
    for i in range(26):
        new_alphabet = alpha[i:] + alpha[:i] #creates new alphabet for each shift
        for c in message:
            index = alpha.index(c)
            new_letter = new_alphabet[index]
            de += new_letter
        print de + ' shift:'+ str(i)
        de = ""
```

give the input gdkkn:

```
decrypt_print(string.ascii_letters)

Enter encryped text: gdkkn
```

this prints:

```
gdkkn shift:0
**hello shift:1** # my bold
ifmmp shift:2
jgnnq shift:3
khoor shift:4
lipps shift:5
mjqqt shift:6
nkrru shift:7
olssv shift:8
pmttw shift:9
qnuux shift:10
rovvy shift:11
spwwz shift:12
tqxxA shift:13
uryyB shift:14
vszzC shift:15
wtAAD shift:16
xuBBE shift:17
yvCCF shift:18
zwDDG shift:19
AxEEH shift:20
ByFFI shift:21
CzGGJ shift:22
DAHHK shift:23
EBIIL shift:24
FCJJM shift:25
```

Comment: import string. If that is something you don't want, I can easily change it.

Comment: the function has an argument, 'alpha'. You replace that with your choice of the alphabet listed at the top. However I edited the post so all you need to is import string

Answer (score 1):

```
message = raw_input('Enter encrypted text: ')
decryption_message = ""
l = message.__len__()
print "Message length : {}".format(l)
for x in range(0, 26):
    for c in message:
        for d in range (l):
            m = ord(c) - 65
            e = (int(m) - int(x)) %26
            ea = e + 65
            decryption_message = decryption_message + chr(ea)
    print "Key = {}, decryption = {}".format(x, decryption_message)
```